# ¿Cómo doy un ancho de 2 columnas en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, xml

Estoy haciendo una app de una calculadora en la cual hay 5 filas, de las cuales 4 tienen 4 columnas y una tiene 3. No consigo cuadrar un botón para que ocupe exactamente el ancho que ocuparían dos columnas (adjunto foto para que se vea el problema).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene un TableLayout y cada fila está metida en un TableRow.
El código en resumen es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/numero0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/boton"
        android:tag="0"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botonPunto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/boton"
        android:tag="."
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botonResultado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/botonIgual"
        android:tag="="
        android:text="="
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</TableRow>
```

Sólo incluyo la última fila que es la que me da problemas. El resto son igual, 4 botones con un layout_weight=1 y un ancho de tipo wrap content.

No quiero ajustarlo manualmente porque quiero que sea adaptable a resoluciones y no se me ocurre otra cosa al fallar el span.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso usar  `android:layout_span="2`" no aplica puesto que tu layout esta separado del layout que contiene los botones de arriba.

Para que funcione correctamente el uso de `android:layout_weight` en todos los elementos que se distribuyen horizontalmente debes definir `android:layout_width="0dp"` y asignar al botón "0" el valor `android:layout_weight="1"` y a los demás botones  android:layout_weight="0.5" para obtener una distribución correcta, donde el botón "0" ocuparía exactamente la mitad del espacio horizontal (dos columnas):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí muestro los cambios que menciono:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/numero0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/boton"
            android:tag="0"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botonPunto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@color/boton"
            android:tag="."
            android:text="."
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botonResultado"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@color/botonIgual"
            android:tag="="
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```